# best way to integrate customer with login and pass from another website?

Tags: magento-1.9, api

My customer have already a big website whose have 200.000,00 customer registered.
Now, we make an store with products related with the site. He wants to integrate the 200000 followers registered (with email and pass) on magento store.

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Are you trying to sync the customers (they can still sign up on the other site and still login to Magento), or are you trying to move all customers over to Magento (the old site will no longer be used).

Comment: I trying to sync, they can still sign up on the other site and still login to Magento

Answer (score 0):

From [here](http://inchoo.net/magento/programming-magento/programmaticaly-adding-new-customers-to-the-magento-store/) you can use

```
$websiteId = Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId();
$store = Mage::app()->getStore();

$customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer");
$customer   ->setWebsiteId($websiteId)
            ->setStore($store)
            ->setFirstname('John')
            ->setLastname('Doe')
            ->setEmail('jd1@ex.com')
            ->setPassword('somepassword');

try{
    $customer->save();
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    Zend_Debug::dump($e->getMessage());
}
```

with a foreach over an object or file containing all your pre existent customers. You will have to insert this code in a controller or in a php file including app/Mage.php